# Why everytime rebuild vs project has to clear the browser history

Tags: visual-studio

The browser is Chrome. I am using Visual studio 2015 with ASP.NET Web Application Project. 
somehow, whenever I rebuild the project,  I have to clear chrome cache first. otherwise, it only loads the previous version of my project.(not showing my changes.) how should I fix this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code on your **Page_Load** Event to avoid the browser *caching* your details.
The browser wouldn't be able to *cache* your details on **Web Forms** no matter how many times your Project is *build*.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {                            
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    }
}
```

---

If you specifically want to remove certain **items**, then use this:

```
Cache.Remove("MyItem");   //Removing the item with the key named 'MyItem'.
```

---

***FYI***: The whole list of cache stored in your browser(**Chrome** for instance) can be seen using:

- Open a new tab in your browser
- Type **about:cache** in the **URL**

You'll be able to see a list of items in cache of the browser.